# moq 4.18.0 doest allow me to use list.IsNullOrEmpty() from Castle.core.internal

Tags: c#, .net, moq

when i update my unit test project to moq 4.18.0 or above, i get the following exception
`Could not load type 'Castle.Core.Internal.CollectionExtensions'`. In my service class im using the static method `IsNullOrEmpty` from Castle.core.internal.
Im not getting this issue for moq versions below 4.18.0.

the resolve the issue for now I'm just creating my own internal `IsNullOrEmpty` method.

Any Idea how to solve this exception from moq?

Comment: The name internal was there presumably for a reason. They didn't used it themselves so they simply removed it. See https://github.com/castleproject/Core/pull/563. In the diff of the pull request you see the old code for that method. Its just a one liner you could put somewhere to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it was stated by [Ralf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/777522/ralf) the `CollectionExtensions` has been removed from the package.

The `IsNullOrEmpty` was implemented like this:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this IEnumerable @this)
{
    return @this == null || @this.GetEnumerator().MoveNext() == false;
}
```

But you can implement like this as well

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this IEnumerable @this)
    => !(@this?.GetEnumerator().MoveNext() ?? false);
```